# Using pipes/streams with Clojure

Tags: clojure, pipe

Other than [Conduit](http://www.intensivesystems.net/tutorials/stream_proc.html) are there any other Clojure modules that deal with streaming/pipes, and if so, what are they?

Basically, I am looking into steaming, because I want a Python and Clojure program to communicate in a very lightweight fashion, like the Clojure program ran and was successful, and is perhaps returning some data. So I have no need for something heavy-duty.

Thank you.

Comment: Conduit looks pretty good, though perhaps a bit heavy. are you looking for something lighter weight?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt lightweight, and I updated the original question based on your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lamina](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina) has everything you seek